# Loading JavaScript File With Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

So running Rails 3.2. In my `assets/javascripts` folder I have the file "`main.js.erb`". The contents of this file are as follows:

```
$(function(){
  $(document).load(alert("Hello"))
})
```

My application.js file is just the default generated after an install initiated with '`rails new`'.

Any ideas as to why the `load` event is not being triggered?

Answer (score 0):

Since your `application.js` is just the default, you probably haven't included the file for usage.

Following are different ways you can include the file:

1. In `app/assets/javscripts/application.js`

   ```
   //= require main
   ```
2. In your template file or layout file eg. app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

   ```
   <%= javascript_include_tag "main" %>
   ```

For further details please refer to [The Asset Pipeline RailsGuides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).

Comment: Hmm.. that was my guess too--it's still not working for some reason though, but thank you!

Comment: Any errors in browser's console?  Do you see the file when you view source?